# What aircraft is this twin prop?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Sorry it's the only picture I have.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE. I am going to edit this question for you, but next time please try to use a more professional language.

Answer (score 5):

The aircraft is almost certainly a Beechcraft B200 or B200C King Air, with a combined Cargo-and-Airstair Door, as can be seen in these photos:

[image]
[(source)](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8335684)

[image]
[(source)](https://cdn.jetphotos.com/full/6/15620_1468607447.jpg)

The airstair door is essentially a door-within-a-door and opens downwards as usual:

[image]
[(source)](http://nnimgt-a.akamaihd.net/transform/v1/crop/frm/storypad-mJpm52jWVuArAFdazE3qPb/a8c0cb85-ee6b-4092-9d81-8f48c7c7bb94.jpg/r0_58_1125_693_w1200_h678_fmax.jpg)

The larger cargo door opens upwards:
[image]
[(source)](http://www.easternairexpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DSC02033-1024x684.jpg)

Comment: I know that two of the photos have the source printed on them but please add your sources for your images.

Comment: Good catch noticing the cargo door.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Beechcraft Super King Air

Judging by the amount of windows it is not the regular King Air

[source](http://www.defenceimagery.mod.uk)

[image: Source]

Comment: Please include the source of your image

Comment: What is a "regular" King Air? Are you referring to the 90?